# Do the Eclipse still use the CVS to control the version of sources?

Tags: eclipse, git, repository, cvs, history

I'm a student from Chungbuk National Univ. in South Korea. Researching mining software repositories. I think I need some history of the eclipse platform in a given period(May 2005).

I looked into the Eclipse web site but I guess the Eclipse development process doesn't choose the CVS any more. I'm not sure about that though.

Below list is the questions organized.

1. Do the developers of Eclipse still use the CVS for controlling version?
2. Whether they use the CVS or not, is there any way to get logs from the CVS history?
3. If they are using GIT for now, how can I get the information (histories and logs)?

Does anyone know how to solve this? Please help me :)

Comment: First of all: what do you mean by _Eclipse_? Eclipse is a hundreds of projects, including IDEs, Equinox, Jetty server and a ton of tools and plugins. Some of them use [Git](http://git.eclipse.org/c/), another - [CVS and SVN](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewsvn/viewvc.cgi/). I did not works with CVS at all, but I know it is possible to transfer repo from SVN to Git with all history. So dig and you'll find!

Comment: These seem to be questions that might be better addressed to the Eclipse project directly.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Do the developers of Eclipse still use the CVS for controlling
   version?**
   From what I can tell the eclipse project has a huge number of subproject using different source control tools, most commonly cvs, svn and git.
2. Whether they use the CVS or not, is there any way to get logs from
   the CVS history?
   Only cvs projects can really get cvs history (although git can act as a cvs server so you can get partial git history if the git repositories has activated their cvs server (which is unlikely)). The history from the public eclipse projects is available to the public. Se www.eclipse.org. Of course you can use subversion to see the subversion history and git to see the git history etc.
3. If they are using GIT for now, how can I get the information
   (histories and logs)?
   For git you use `git clone` to clone the repo you want to look at and then `git log` to view the history. You can learn git on www.git-scm.com